# Linq-to-sql multiple tables query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a following method:

```
public List<object> GetLoginValues(String user, String pass)
{
   using (db = new DCDataContext())
   {
      List<object> x = (from u in db.users
                      join t in db.userTypes on u.type equals t.typeID
                      where u.loginName == user &&
                      u.password == pass &&
                      u.isActive == true
                      select new
                      {
                          u.userID,
                          u.loginName,
                          u.userCode,
                          u.type,
                          u.team,
                          t.typeName
                      }).ToList();
      return x;
   }
}
```

Which obviously doesn't work. I need this method to return the result of this join. Preferably into a `List`. I want to know if this can be done without having to make a class containing the properties for both tables, since I'm using `linq-to-sql` and already have classes for every table.

What type should I return in order to make this query/method work properly?

Comment: I just updated my answer did that work?

Answer (score 0):

The below method will return the result of join into a List.

You need to specify the columns, which you are going to use from the two tables by joining it. You must specify the columns (property) because join doesn't know which need to be selected. And also its good practice. Selecting required columns instead of selecting all the columns properties.

```
public dynamic GetLoginValues(String user, String pass)
{
    using (db = new DCDataContext())
    {
        var x = (from u in db.users
               join t in db.userTypes on u.type equals t.typeID
               where u.loginName == user &&
               u.password == pass &&
               u.isActive == true
               select new
                   {
                       u.userID,
                       u.loginName,
                       u.userCode,
                       u.type,
                       u.team,
                       t.typeName
                   }).ToList();
      return x; //returns the list of values
   }
}
```

Yes if you don't want to use custom classes, then the above code will not require to create additional custom classes.

**Call the Method Like below:**

```
YourClassName dbObj = new YourClassName();
var loginDetailsList = dbObj.GetLoginValues("RJK", "123456");
```